# Custom Post Type permissions

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a new custom `post_type`.
The problem is that I can only publish/edit them as administrator. (via the admin panel). But I can't do that with Editor/Author user roles. It doesn't show up in the Editor/Author admin menu. Only in the Administrator one.

this is my code:

```
/* Downloads for admin menu */
    add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type_downloads' );
    function create_post_type_downloads() {
        register_post_type( 'download_type',
            array(
                'labels' => array(
                    'name' => __( 'Downloads' ),
                    'singular_name' => __( 'download' )
                ),
                'taxonomies' => array('category'),
                'public' => true,
                'has_archive' => true,
                'rewrite' => true,
            )
        );
    }

    add_post_type_support( 'download_type',array('thumbnail'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the plugin `Role Scoper`, it was the one making the trouble.

Comment: Yes. Should i do anything special for that reason?

Comment: nothing ... just a complete description of the answer to help others who would be visiting this question